# Node.JS + Apache - Cannot GET

Tags: node.js, apache, proxy

I'm trying to use Apache and Node.JS at the same time but it is not working as expected.

```
// Apache 
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyRequests Off
  ServerName mydomain.com
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/
```

And for my server.js

```
// Node
  const express = require ('express');
  const server = express();

  server.get('/', function(req,res){
    return res.send('The code works fine here');
  });

  server.get('/foo', function(req,res){
    return res.send('Here => Cannot GET /foo');
  });

  server.get('/foo2', function(req,res){
    return res.send('Here too => Cannot GET /foo2');
  });

  server.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('server is only working for "/" ')
  });
```

`mydomain.com` works perfectly, but I cannot find a way to make all the other sub-domains `mydomain.com/*` to work. Can someone give me a light?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Apache reverse proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html)

Add this configuration to your apache conf.

> ProxyPass "/nodeapp"  "http:/localhost:8443"

You can access node application by http://www.example.com/nodeapp

A reverse proxy is a type of proxy server that retrieves resources on behalf of a client from the server. These resources are then returned to the client as if they originated from the web server itself.

Comment: it did not work:  `Reason: DNS lookup failure for: localhost:8443br`

Comment: `ProxyPass "/" "http:/localhost:3000/"` now it works, I really don't know why, but the quotes made it.